# PHP include and SSI include, what do search engines read?

Tags: php, include, search-engine, ssi

I am going to dynamically include the `<head>` part of my code so that I can change multiple pages from one file.

my 'include.php' will look something like:

```
<?php echo '<meta name="description" content="page description"><meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">'; ?>
```

Which is faster:

- `<?php include 'include.php'; ?>`
- `<!-- #include file="include.php" -->`

Also will both be readable by a search engine crawler?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search engines will read the content returned by the web server, whether generated by PHP code or SSI include.

As for your question about which is faster, it depends, and you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd spent ages on google but mostly all I could find was information on the SSI method, this has been most comprehensive :)